# How to scan this particular string?

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have a string like this:`01/22/2014 09:00 pm GMT`

How to i get the time only :`09:00 pm`

Here is the my code

```
NSString *stringValue=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[dataForLoading valueForKey:@"realtime_time"]];

NSLog(@"String Value:%@",stringValue);

NSScanner *scanner=[NSScanner scannerWithString:stringValue];
```

Comment: `NSDateFormatter`? Or use `NSRange`, or maybe `componentsSeparatedByString` if always the same. But you may want to use NSTimeZone, so NSDateFormatter should be the solution to use.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no effort on the part of the asker.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
NSString *input = @"01/22/2014 09:00 pm GMT";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterInput = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterInput setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatterInput dateFromString:input];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterOutput = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterOutput setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString *output = [dateFormatterOutput stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"Output: %@", output);
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement on arturgrigor's solution is to not alloc/init another `NSDateFormatter` as they're very expensive and thus you should refrain from using more than you need.

```
NSString *input = @"01/22/2014 09:00 pm GMT";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterInput = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterInput setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatterInput dateFromString:input];
[dateFormatterInput setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatterInput stringFromDate:date]);
```